# Shapes-tool creating a vector mask every time, cannot seem to fix in CS3?

Tags: graphics, photoshop, cs3, raster-graphics

Every time I create a shape using the shape tool, it places a vector mask on top of this. I don't know how I enabled this but it does not do it on my laptop version, only my desktop.

I can seem to disable this problem I am having. Even reinstalling and restoring defaults I cannot seem to stop this.

Very frustrating, anyone have a fix for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question would be better asked on Superuser.com.  In fact, check this out:  https://superuser.com/questions/87343/photoshop-not-creating-vector-masksw-shape-tool